# Store diferrent IDs in an Array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'll describe what i wanna do.

I have table which imports the data from database and for every row i have a checkbox with the ID from the database(primary key). It looks like this.

cb = checkbox

cb id=1 | name | content | bla bla

and so on.

I am able to delete 1 row at a time, but i want to delete multiple rows by checking multitple cheboxes and press the delete button. I was thinking of storing those checkboxes ids into and array once you check any of them and then do a loop when i press the button to delete the selected ones.

My single delete button code looks like this(this button use it's own ID to delete, which is the same with the checkbox on the same row):

```
$('.del').click(function(){
var myid = $(this).attr('id');
$.post('newsdel.php', {delete_id:myid}, function(data) {
    if(data == 'true') {
        $('#'+myid).fadeOut();
        var rowCount = $('#count tr').length;
        if(rowCount < 3) {
        window.location = '?news=1';
        }
        } else {
        alert('Could not delete!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You seem to have an approach in mind. Look for the jQuery `.each()` iterator.

Comment: first, you are not deleting them, you are just hiding them using 
  `$('#'+myid).fadeOut();` for deletion use 
 `$('#'+myid).remove();`

Comment: He might be deleting them in his PHP file. You can check with `.each()` what checkboxes are checked and send them as an `array` to your PHP file (which is also better because you have 1 call back to the server and 1 query to your database).

Comment: @niklaz The POST request to the PHP file is doing the delete. On return of the request the rows are being faded out.

Comment: i'm deleting them from database with the script from newsdel.php . I used fade out just for effect. refreshing the page after won't show them again cuz that occurs another query.

Comment: Ok. i'll look over the .each() statement. I'm new to jquery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I know, but to be thorough, it is better to remove DOM element, then to hide it. It is still there on fadeOut, maybe better for  saving ajax callback and server time.

Comment: @niklaz tnx for advice. I'll remove it after the fadeout completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one of solutions:
First add to each checkbox css class like: "checkbox-option" 
to delete button add css class 'delete-btn'

Then this jQuery code:

```
 $('.delete-btn').click(function(){
      $('.checkbox-option').each(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked'){
      //then goes larger part of your code: 
      var myid = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('newsdel.php', {delete_id:myid}, function(data) {
         if(data == 'true') {
            $('#'+myid).fadeOut();
            var rowCount = $('#count tr').length;
            if(rowCount < 3) {
            window.location = '?news=1';
            }
            } else {
            alert('Could not delete!');
            }
         });
      }

       });
    });
```

This was in case when using your part of code, but it sends ajax request for each. Other would be instead, while iterating, to collect all ids in array ( and then serialize) or separate by comma sign ( and then split in server side script), and then send one ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

considering your checkboxes have class checkbox

```
function getCheckedRows() {
var checkedRows = [];
  $('.checkbox').each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          checkedRows.push($(this).attr('id'); //assuming id is the row id 
      } 
  });
return checkedRows;
}
$('.del').click(function(){
var rowIds = getCheckedRows();
for(var myid in rowIds) {
   $.post('newsdel.php', {delete_id:myid}, function(data) {
    if(data == 'true') {
        $('#'+myid).remove();
        var rowCount = $('#count tr').length;
        if(rowCount < 3) {
        window.location = '?news=1';
        }
        } else {
        alert('Could not delete!');
        }
    });
}
});
```